# VBA code to select filter value from drop down menu on one sheet and apply filter in a table on another worksheet - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

Very novice, trying to write a VBA code in EXcel 2010 to select filter value from a drop down list located in cell A1 of Sheet1 and apply filter value on column 4 of a data range A7:S1000 located on Sheet2.
Below is the code, inserted in Sheet1, that I am using, but returning nothing.
Where am I getting it wrong?
Thanks a a lot.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Cell with dropdown where value to be selected
    Const DropDown = "a1"
    ' Sheet with data range to apply filter
    Const TableSheet = "Sheet2"
    ' Top left cell of the data range
    Const TableRange = "a7"
    If Not Intersect(Range(DropDown), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Range(DropDown).Value = "" Then
            Worksheets(TableSheet).ShowAllData
        Else
            Worksheets(TableSheet).Range(TableRange).AutoFilter _
                Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range(DropDown).Value
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the 'Application.EnableEvents = False' line and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @kevin9999. Thanks. Tried removing Application.EnableEvents = False' line, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

@Scottyfrog I was hoping the advice I offered above in the comments would do the trick, but unfortunately it didn’t.  As an alternative, I rewrote your code in a way that was *simpler for me to understand.*  I tested it on my own computer & it seems to work OK.

In addition, a possible cause of your problem could be that the filter couldn’t find any values that matched your criteria.  I’ve added a test to your code that will tell you if it can’t find any values that match.

Let me know how it goes, and if it works, please uptick the answer.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 
    If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        
    Worksheets("Sheet2").ShowAllData
    
    Else
    
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D:D"), Range("A1")) = 0 Then
        
            MsgBox "The Filtered value doesn't exist in column D on sheet 2"
            
            Exit Sub
        
        End If
    
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A7:S7").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range("A1").Value
    
    End If
    
End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: @Scottyfrog please advise if the code provided works or not.

Comment: Aps for late reply was on AL. yes, code works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Scottyfrog you're welcome, and please 'accept' the answer by giving it an uptick. Cheers :)

Comment: How do you give answer an uptick?

Comment: To the left of the answer, you'll see up & down arrows with a 0 between them. Just click on the top arrow. Thanks Scotty.